# Service Bus (On Premise) (1.1) and "High Availability" : Connection String

Tags: azureservicebus, servicebus

I have a question about Service Bus (On Premise) (1.1) and "High Availability".

Below are 2 images from Microsoft.  From this article

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj193012%28v=azure.10%29?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

My question is the "connection string" to Service Bus.

I have locally setup 3 machines on my Farm.  Machine1A(the very first thing I installed SB on) and then adding on 2 more machines for the farm.  "Machine2" and "Machine3"

However, my connection string (from my clients) is pointing to Machine1A.

```
Endpoint=sb://Machine1A.fullyqualified.domain.name.com/ServiceBusDefaultNamespace;StsEndpoint=https://Machine1A.fullyqualified.domain.name.com:9355/ServiceBusDefaultNamespace;RuntimePort=9354;ManagementPort=9355
```

I don't understand, if Machine1A does down..........clients cannot connect to it.

Is there a "farm" connection string?  Can the only machines that crash...be Machine2 and Machine3 (Machines 2-N) ?

What connection string (fully qualified machine name) do I use for High Availability?

[image: 3 machines on Farm]

[image: If one machine on Farm goes down]

Other articles I've read on this subject:

http://www.planetgeek.ch/2014/12/10/service-bus-for-windows-server-high-availability/

https://haishibai.blogspot.com/2012/08/walkthrough-setting-up-development.html

"Scaling" (Below url)

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn441424.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/meamcs/2013/12/08/recommended-practices-service-bus-for-windows-server/

*"Make sure it is highly available (HA): HA can be fully satisfied only when both service and database layers are HA. Service layer HA can be accomplished by having at least 3 servers in the ring. ..................  Please note that Service bus v1.1 supports up-to 5 servers in the ring"*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
To get ConnectionString Use the following cmdlet 
Get-SBAuthorizationRule -Namespace YourNamespaceName

You have to Export and import the certificates to use the same connectionstring in your client machine.
```

For Your Reference: [click here..](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj192993.aspx)

Comment: Ohhhhhhhhhhh!   I see it now.  The connection string is : sb://Machine1A.fullyqualified.domain.name.com/ServiceBusDefaultNamespace,sb://Machine2.fullyqualified.domain.name.com/ServiceBusDefaultNamespace,sb://Machine3.fullyqualified.domain.name.com/ServiceBusDefaultNamespace